# Filter rows in DataFrame where certain conditions are met?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with relevant stock information that looks like this.

[Screenshot of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8aKr.png)

I need it so that if the 'close' from one row is different from the 'open' in the next row a new dataframe will be created storing the ones that fulfill this criteria. I would like that all of the values from the row to be saved in the new dataframe. To clarify, I would like the two rows where this happens to be stored in the new dataframe.

```
DataFrame as text as requested: 

    timestamp            open    high    low     close   volume
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00  129.16  130.98  128.68  130.24  4.714333e+04
1   2020-01-01 08:00:00  130.24  132.40  129.87  132.08  5.183323e+04
2   2020-01-01 16:00:00  132.08  133.05  129.74  130.77  4.579396e+04
3   2020-01-02 00:00:00  130.72  130.78  128.69  129.26  6.606601e+04
4   2020-01-02 08:00:00  129.23  130.28  128.90  129.59  4.849893e+04
5   2020-01-02 16:00:00  129.58  129.78  126.38  127.19  9.919212e+04
6   2020-01-03 00:00:00  127.19  130.15  125.88  128.86  1.276414e+05
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the DataFrame as text. `print(df.to_string())` should suffice. You do not need to include every row, but please include every column.

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information.

Comment: I have provided the DataFrame as text but I'm not sure how useful this can be to you guys. I formated it how it is supposed to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `Series.shift`

```py
>>> df['close'] != df['open'].shift(-1)
0  2020-01-01    False
1  2020-01-01    False
2  2020-01-01     True
3  2020-01-02     True
4  2020-01-02     True
5  2020-01-02    False
6  2020-01-03     True
```

This compares the `close` value in one row to the `open` value of the next row ("shifted" one row ahead).

You can then select the rows for which the condition is True.

```py
>>> df[df['close'] != df['open'].shift(-1)]
             timestamp    open    high     low   close     volume
2 2020-01-01  16:00:00  132.08  133.05  129.74  130.77   45793.96
3 2020-01-02  00:00:00  130.72  130.78  128.69  129.26   66066.01
4 2020-01-02  08:00:00  129.23  130.28  128.90  129.59   48498.93
6 2020-01-03  00:00:00  127.19  130.15  125.88  128.86  127641.40
```

This only returns the second of the two rows; to get the first, we can then shift back one, and unite the two conditions.

```py
>>> row_condition = df['close'] != df['open'].shift(-1)
>>> row_before = row_condition.shift(1)
>>> df[row_condition | row_before]
             timestamp    open    high     low   close     volume
0 2020-01-01  00:00:00  129.16  130.98  128.68  130.24   47143.33
1 2020-01-01  08:00:00  130.24  132.40  129.87  132.08   51833.23
2 2020-01-01  16:00:00  132.08  133.05  129.74  130.77   45793.96
3 2020-01-02  00:00:00  130.72  130.78  128.69  129.26   66066.01
4 2020-01-02  08:00:00  129.23  130.28  128.90  129.59   48498.93
5 2020-01-02  16:00:00  129.58  129.78  126.38  127.19   99192.12
6 2020-01-03  00:00:00  127.19  130.15  125.88  128.86  127641.40
```

Providing a textual sample of the DataFrame is useful because this can be copied directly into a Python session; I would have had to manually type the content of your screenshot otherwise.